# Filter phone numbers out of message

Tags: php

I'd like to filter phone numbers out of the users message. The problem is ofcourse that a phone number can be written in different ways. Like:

0612345678
06 123 45 678
+31 (0)612345678
+31 (0)6 12 34 56 78

But I've got absolutely no clue how to do this and I'm pritty stuck. Can anyone help me a bit?

Thanks!

Edit:
In the meanwhile I came with this regular expression: "/(\d|\s){5,}/im". This filters every number of at least 5 characters and ignores the spaces. That way, all numbers from my previous example will be filtered.

Comment: This will be difficult to get into a general rule. How would you tell a phone number apart from a "normal" number?

Comment: I decided to make this rule: as soon as a number (after the spaces have been removed) contains at least 5 characters, it can be considered a phone number. European notation doesn't use the '-' char like US notation.

Comment: What countries do you need to check for phone numbers for?

For example, North American phone numbers are ten digits, and the first and fourth digits can't be 0 or 1. They can be written out as seven digits (555-1212), ten digits (455-555-1212) or eleven digits (1-455-555-1212). Spaces, dashes, periods and parentheses are commonly uses as separators.

You could write something like \+?1?[-\. ]?\\(?[2-9][0-9]{2}\\)?[-\. ]?[2-9][0-9]{2}[-\. ]?[0-9]{4}. 

The problem is you could get false positives. For example, ISBNs are also 10 (or 13) digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regular expressions. This link pertains to python, but you can use these patterns by calling the PHP functions: http://diveintopython3.ep.io/regular-expressions.html#phonenumbers

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php